# how to use global Event listener?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

i want to communicate between two applications, whenever blackberry messenger is open then at that time my application can notified that,this blackberry messenger is started.

how could i do with the use of global event listener..

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this primer here

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/What_Is_-_Global_Events_and_Global_Event_Listeners.html?nodeid=800527&vernum=0

Comment: An answer that is just a link isn't a very good answer, even when the link is working.

Answer (score 1):

2 applications OR Background application and foreground application can communicated through GlobalEventListener

- Implemented the GlobalEventListener interface
- Register for global event using the below line

  addGlobalEventListener(instance of class which implement the GlobalEventListener );
- From background application 
  post the global events (for other application) using the below line

  ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().postGlobalEvent(MainWindow.GUID);

**Note** : postGlobalEvent methods having the 4 overloaded versions 
So you can pass addition info as well if require

- Following method of GlobalEventListener interface method will listen the global event

  public void eventOccurred(long guid, int data0, int data1, Object object0, Object object1)

see the links for more details

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/GlobalEventListener.html
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#addGlobalEventListener%28net.rim.device.api.system.GlobalEventListener%29